# How do I get React to respond to media queries?

Tags: reactjs, media-queries

I would like a React component to be responsive to an external state, in this case the size of the viewport. Do I accomplish this internally to my component or do I do a media query which passes the viewport as a size property to the initial render?

Comment: Have your render logic change based on `window.innerWidth` or `.innerHeight` being less than or greater than some value.

Comment: Are these numbers accurate @keizom ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this project: https://github.com/wearefractal/react-responsive, it seems to be exactly what you need.