# Respond to media queries in React js?

Tags: reactjs, react-responsive

So I solved this problem with using useEffect and innerwidth. However i dont know if it is reliable way. Sometimes it is off by couple of pixels. This is my code:

```
const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState({
    width: undefined,
    height: undefined,
});

useEffect(() => {
    // Handler to call on window resize
    function handleResize() {
        // Set window width/height to state
        setWindowSize({
            width: window.innerWidth,
            height: window.innerHeight,
        });
    }
    // Add event listener
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    // Call handler right away so state gets updated with initial window size
    handleResize();
    // Remove event listener on cleanup
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
}, []);

  return (
    // some code
      {windowSize.width < 768 && <div>Hi There</div>}
    // some code
  )
```

Or is it better to solve it like this using react-responsive:
[How do I get React to respond to media queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32289806/how-do-i-get-react-to-respond-to-media-queries)

Comment: if you only want to hide and show element based on viewport, you can easily do it with media queries

Comment: yeah sure. This is just a simple example to show my point. I will need to use it in addition with some calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several premade React hooks for this.

Two good examples:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-hook/media-query
- https://usehooks.com/useMedia/

Essentially what you want to do is use `window.matchMedia` instead of comparing the width and height of the window.

To be clear, only use this when you need the information in your JavaScript if you're simply hiding or showing something, use CSS media queries instead as they have much better performance.